# How would I modify the following JavaScript to change color on startup instead of onClick?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to remove the button and simply have the legend symbol display red from the beginning with no option for changing color. Sample below

http://jsfiddle.net/WrVFn/1/

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Joseph - My standard rate for doing other people's work for them is slightly higher than "free" :) Teaching people who want to learn .. that's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `color` option to initialize a series with a specific color, both on the chart and on the legend:

http://jsfiddle.net/WrVFn/17/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        color: 'red'    
    }]
}, function(chart){


});
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/WrVFn/15/

You have a function that executes code when the chart is loaded.  Within that you put a function that executes code when a button is clicked.  Just take the code from the button click function and put it directly in the chart load function.  All I did is comment out two lines of code to get what you are looking for.

I presume you can manage deleting the button on your own. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
}, function(chart){
        chart.series[0].legendLine.attr({
            stroke: 'red'
        });

        chart.series[0].legendSymbol.attr({
            stroke: 'red',
            fill: 'red'
        });
});
```